# How do I return an html file in a Google App Engine response?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, server, google-cloud-datastore

Using the examples Google provides there they often encode the html responses by using:

```
self.response.write( "<html><p>Some stuff!</p></html>" )
```

This is a terrible way to hardcode html and in cases where I want to send back a nice looking page or a prefab, nicely designed response page it seems there ought to be a way to redirect the user directly to an actual *nice_response.html*.

I can't seem to find any example or docs on how to do this. Am I approaching it wrong or is there a simple way to direct a request to a *real* HTML page without hardcoding the response html?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is templating. Take a look at this page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates?hl=fr